# Python tkinter text widget noutra definição não permite insert

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, text

Sou novo na programação e no python. Gostava de poder inserir numa definição
uma informação da caixa que foi criada noutra definição. Como é isso possivel? 
Conforme o código, que segue em anexo, o programa dá erro. Obrigado

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Demo1:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.grid()

        grupo1 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.frame, text='Nomes Pilotos')
        grupo1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky = 'w')
        botao1 = ttk.Button(grupo1, width=18, text='Amaral SILVA', command = lambda : self.escreve('Amaral'))
        botao1.grid(padx=10, pady=5)
        botao2 = ttk.Button(grupo1, width=18, text='Jorge CASTRO', command = lambda : self.escreve('Jorge'))
        botao2.grid(padx=10, pady=5)

        grupo2 = ttk.LabelFrame(master, text = 'Informação:')
        grupo2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 4, padx = 10, pady = 1, sticky = 'w')
        texto = tk.Text(grupo2, height=10, width=20, fg='white', bg='#3D7475',font=('Consolas', 12))
        texto.grid()

    def escreve(self, jogador):

        texto.insert(END, jogador, ' é fixe!')

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o problema está acontecendo porque a variável `texto` não tem uma referência dentro da classe, portanto, o método `escreve` não consegue acessar essa variável.

Se o problema for esse, uma possível solução é criar (e utilizar) a variável `texto` como propriedade da classe `Demo1`, exemplo: `self.texto` ao invés de `texto`.

Abaixo, segue o programa com essa modificação:

```
#!python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class Demo1:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.grid()

        grupo1 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.frame, text='Nomes Pilotos')
        grupo1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky = 'w')
        botao1 = ttk.Button(grupo1, width=18, text='Amaral SILVA', command = lambda : self.escreve('Amaral'))
        botao1.grid(padx=10, pady=5)
        botao2 = ttk.Button(grupo1, width=18, text='Jorge CASTRO', command = lambda : self.escreve('Jorge'))
        botao2.grid(padx=10, pady=5)

        grupo2 = ttk.LabelFrame(master, text = 'Informação:')
        grupo2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 4, padx = 10, pady = 1, sticky = 'w')

        # Aqui, mudar de texto para self.texto
        self.texto = tk.Text(grupo2, height=10, width=20, fg='white', bg='#3D7475',font=('Consolas', 12))
        self.texto.grid()

    def escreve(self, jogador):
        # Aqui, mudar de texto para self.texto, indicar o prefixo tk.END.
        # Concatenar o nome do jogador com a string através do operador '+'
        self.texto.insert(tk.END, jogador + ' é fixe!\n')

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

<sub>testado com Python 2.7.11</sub>